# Add\remove row based on value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I got a table_1 that has 2 columns in (Q and R) the end with checkboxes.
I want to create and secondary table_2 that has dependency on the table_1 in such a way that it imports rows from Table_1 when I have TRUE value in column Q but removes it when I set value to TRUE in column R.

I tried using Filter, but it does not work after I alter data in table_1.
Basically, I want to make it work all the time. Not just once.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I9RwXYBeibhL-mQBsSZHbB5QEBD24gbUBWldBucNmsw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

You should use FILTER formula or QUERY formula.

Let's say you want to have a Sheet2 based on Sheet1 where you show only orders paid (P) but not delivered (Q) yet:

Source sheet according to your link:

[image]

Solution:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!B2:R;Sheet1!P2:P=TRUE;Sheet1!Q2:Q=False)
```

First parameter: Sheet1!B2:R tells what will be displayed (all rows from 2 to the end and columns from B to R)

Second and Third parameters set conditions that are checked for each row separately.

[image]

If you want to have tick boxes in Sheet2, you should select P and Q columns and use Menu --> Insert --> Tick box.
It will change format of these columns but will not affect the content.